# a router with multiple parameters not work with express.static

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, static

I have made the express router with parameters 
router.get ('/add') and it working fine. but when I added router.get ('/edit/:id'), express.static does not work, CSS and JavaScript external not working, what the problem with multiple parameters?

This my static settings

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'public'))

Comment: First off, why the spaces in your routes? Whats up with that? 
Secondly, `__dirname` does not append the directory separator...

Answer (score 0):

`__dirname` only returns path of your working directory not `/`end of your directory so you have to use `/` before your static file directory like.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
```

for multiple parameter with URL you have to write `route` according your need.

```
app.get('edit/:id/:value', (req, res) => {
    /** for get these value from request use */
    let id = req.params.id
    let value = req.params.value
})
```

and your request URL should look like

```
http://localhost:port/edit/34/988978898
```